# Customers Data not display M2

Tags: magento2

We are working on Magneto 2.3.0, If there is a new customer login then some data is not visible, someone can tell why this is happening

Migration M1 To M2

Error : **var/log**

> main.CRITICAL: Validate class not found from basename
>   'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' {"exception":"[object]
>   (Zend_Validate_Exception(code: 0): Validate class not found from
>   basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' at
>   /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate.php:244)"} []

[image]

Comment: Please do reindex and clear cache. And then check it.

Comment: I did everything but nothing happened

Comment: First check-in the database that all value exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in the table **customer_grid_flat** whether it have data or not.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please add it to the comment box.

Comment: Thank you sir, but this problem was solved

Comment: But main problem :
main.CRITICAL: Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Validate_Exception(code: 0): Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' at /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate.php:244)"} []

Comment: @RanjeetGautam Do you use PLESK?